# Getting excel range from argument example javascript api

Tags: excel, office-js, custom-functions-excel

I am trying to write a custom function in scriptlab to check if a value is in a selected range, however I cannot seem to figure out how to actually accept that range as the function argument. The example function I have created is below (where I thought range would equal something like "A1:D1"):

```
/** @CustomFunction */
async function exists(range): any {
    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet()
    sheet.getRange(range)
...
}
```

This however results in a `$CALC!` error. Any tips or ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Custom Function doesn't support to call office.js API yet. Please stay turned, that will be enabled soon.